# Сделать группировку по похожим строкам в списке

Tags: c#, list

У меня есть список `List<T>`

```
List<Result> listRez = new List<Result>();
```

Я хочу сгруппировать их по двум полям.

```
var data = listRez.GroupBy(x => new { x.trafficSegment, x.name }).ToList();
```

Все работает хорошо, однако стоит задача в том чтобы группировать по похожим словам.

Например, вот такие строки есть в полях `name`

```
мастер иванов
мастер иванов23
мастер иванов 4 4
```

Взять например алгоритм `Левенштейна` для сравнения строк и пробежаться по списку. Как это сделать?

Comment: Ну получили вы расстояние Левенштейна. А что дальше?

Comment: @VladD я имею в виду сравнивать их по расстоянию Левенштейна?

Comment: Как ты собираешься группировать такой список слов : 
Иванова
Иван
Новая
Новатор
Ивано-франковск
Инновация

Comment: Необходимо четко знать что для тебя похожие слова. Похожие слова это слова которые имеют внутри себя подстроку определенной длинны ? Но при этом длинна строки должна быть больше 3х (разные окончания например тся, ться и прочее) или что. Сверху список можно сгруппировать по подстроке "Иван" и по подстроке "Нова".

Comment: @ParanoidPanda есть такая вещь как расстояние Левенштейна. Мне нужны те слова в которых процент похоженсти >=90%

Comment: @Radzhab ну так вот я представил список слов. чисто по логике как сгруппировать Иванова Иван и Новая. Если и там и там расстояние одинаковое. Либо Иван идет в группу Иванова или в группу Новая, либо они идут в одну группу.

Comment: @Radzhab: Окей. А если у вас расстояние между первым и вторым 90%, между вторым и третьим 90%, а между первым и третьим 80%? У вас пропадёт транзитивность.

Comment: @VladD. Вы правы, понял свою ошибку. Теперь думаю пойти другим путем. Убрать все ненужно, однако. Как пропустить один из параметров через метод? var data = listRez.GroupBy(x => new { x.trafficSegment, x.name }).ToList();

Comment: @VladD. У меня есть метод Remover, я хочу сделать вот так var data = listRez.GroupBy(x => new { x.trafficSegment, Remover(x.name) }).ToList();
но системе это не нравится

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Помогу, чем могу: Стивен Тауб в своей книге [Patterns for Parallel Programming](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222) (можно скачать бесплатно) приводит способ распараллеливания алгоритма Левенштейна.

Comment: @Radzhab: А если так: `var data = listRez.GroupBy(x => new { x.trafficSegment, name = Remover(x.name) }).ToList();`?